# Recommended way of installing packages on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

What's the recommended way of installing any programming packages on Arch? Searching for them on the AUR and installing them from there (or create a PKGBUILD file to make a package yourself) or using a package manager?

I started off by installing stuff from pacman after reading this [article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76389/recommended-way-of-installing-python-packages-on-arch) for python and I'm about to start with node.js and npm is the suggested package manager for node.js packages. There is no clear answer even on this [page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179535). But I'm thinking of sticking to packman and AUR, but not sure why I should do it and how would it help me if I continue doing what I do. (which is using pacman for installing programming packages)

Answer (score 0):

If the package you need is in the official repos, just install it with pacman, of course.

Otherwise, the path of least resistance is to use the language specific package managers, but you always have the option of packaging on your own, it's very easy on Arch.