# Install OpenSSL from source

Tags: software-installation, openssl, source

I installed [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) from source by:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2h/
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But when I type openssl on the command line, it says 'The program 'openssl' is currently not installed'. What should I do?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7899/9812, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42567/9812, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264562/9812.

Comment: I disagree with the proposed duplicate. This isn't about where things *should* be installed, or even *how* to install some piece of software (OpenSSL in this particular case). Rather, this is clearly about where the software *actually ended up* and why it can't be executed by giving *just the name of the binary* on the command line.

Comment: Alex, please note that your commands were to download one version (OpenSSL 1.0.2h, which is current at this time), but unpack, build and install another (1.0.0a, which is outdated, "out of support and should not be used", besides probably having some security-related bugs that have been fixed since 2013).

Comment: My bad, I fixed it,

Comment: Also see [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. It discusses other options, like `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`. It also discusses how to add an RPATH. You might be surprised to learn what `ldd /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl` returns. It may be using `libssl` and `libcrypto` from `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your prefix you will need to run something like `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl`.

If you don't want to type the full pathname then you can add the `/usr/local/openssl/bin` directory to your PATH, or you can symlink the `openssl` command into `/usr/local/bin` (assuming that's on your PATH).
e.g.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Note that either of these, without additional steps, means the OP won't be able to immediately read the man pages (which are likely in /usr/local/openssl/share/man) etc.

Comment: @toszter - you should open this as a new question, not as a comment